# no candidates for error compile error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I am trying to compile my application and it keeps running into "no match for 'operator<<'...  it is not clear what the exact error of the program seems to be because he object is configured correctly as far as I can see.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
class MortgageCalc
{
protected:
    float term;
public:
    void setData(float, float, float);
    float setTerm ();
    float monthly;
    float total;
    float interest;
        float setLoan(void);  //mutator
        float setIntrest(void);     //mutator
        float setYears(void);
    int years;
    float loan;
};

void MortgageCalc::setData(float l, float i, float y)
{
   loan = l;
   interest = i;
   years = y;
   setTerm();
}

float MortgageCalc::setTerm()
{  //simple interest calculation with power calc to establish whole number translation
     term = pow((1 + ((interest/100) / 12)), (12 * years));
     return term;
}

float MortgageCalc::setLoan(void)
{  //returns loan amt to private member
   return loan;
}

float MortgageCalc::setIntrest(void)
{  //returns interest amt to private member
    return interest;
}

float MortgageCalc::setYears(void)
{  //returns years to private member
   return years;
}

class mPayment : public MortgageCalc
{
public:
    int monthly()
    {
        return ((loan * ((interest/100) / 12) * term ) / (term - 1));
    }
};

class tPayment : public mPayment
{
public:
    int total()
    {
        return (monthly() * (years * 12));

    }
};

class iPayment : public tPayment
{
public:
    int plusInterest()
    {
        return (total() - loan);
    }
};

int main()
{
double loan(0), interest(0);
int years = 0;
MortgageCalc mort1;

    cout << "Enter the total loan amount on your mortgage loan: $";  //established loan variable
        cin >> loan;
    cout << "Enter the interest rate (in whole #'s only): ";  //establishes interest rate variable
        cin >> interest;
    cout << "Enter the length of the loan in years: "; //establishes term of payments
        cin >> years;
mort1.setData(loan, interest, years);

mPayment m;
       cout << "Monthly payment due is " << m.monthly() << "." << endl;

tPayment t;
        cout << "Total payment will be " << t.total() << "." << endl;

iPayment i;
        cout << "Total payment plus Interest will be " << i.plusInterest() << "." << endl;

return 0;
};
```

Comment: You've completely changed the question, after answers were already posted. Don't do that....

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << "Total payment plus Interest will be " << i.plusInterest << "." << endl;
```

`plusInterest` is a class method pointer. Unsurprisingly, `std::ostream` has no clue what to do with a class method pointer, and is rightfully voicing its very strong objection, to such a preposterous proposition that it knows what to do with some strange class's method pointer.

You probably meant to write:

```
cout << "Total payment plus Interest will be " << i.plusInterest() << "." << endl;
```

Now, that's a proper function call, that returns an `int`, and `std::ostream` is now delighted to take this `int`, and do its magic with it.

Comment: Thanks bud, been staring too long and missed this, it compiles fine now, but some reason, the output is all '0'  Any thoughts?

Comment: @haynstyle Because the things you're printing out are 0.

Comment: @haynstyle FWIW: You never set the `monthly` or `total` fields, but you have `monthly()` and `total()`methods

Comment: The reason it's printing all zeroes is because the objects whose values you print, `m`, `t`, and `i`, have never been initialized with anything. Just because you initialize the values in a completely unrelated object called `mort1`, doesn't mean that `m`, `t`, and `i` will magically have the same values that `mort1` has.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I went ahead and placed initializer through call's "float MortgageCalc::setLoan(void)"  that should draw out the number when the input is entered into the field but it still outputs weird numbers.  Unless there is a better way to initaize it?

Comment: I don't really understand what you just said. You should post another question, with the current version of the code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I updated/ edited my code above for review

Comment: Ok. My analysis of why you're getting all 0s, and/or garbage, is still true. You initialized neither `m`, nor `t`, nor `i`. They are not initialized. Never been. Only `mort1` is initialized. Just because you initialized the values in `mort1` doesn't mean that the other three, completely independent objects, will be initialized with anything.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  Shouldnt the initailization be handled by the class constructors?  m.monthly should call on constructor monthly() which should return the value of "return ((loan * ((interest/100) / 12) * term ) / (term - 1));"   Is that not the correct understanding?

Comment: That is correct. But "interest" and "term", in that class instance, have never been initialized. What part of "neither m, t, nor i are initialized" you are unable to understand? You have "mort1" with loan, term, and other class members. You also have "m", "t", and "i", also with the same class members (inherited). You invoked "mort1.setData()", which initializes mort1's loan and term, but you have done absolutely nothing to initialize "m", "t", and "i"'s loan and term. You have four completely different, independent objects. Initialize one object ***does not*** automatically initialize others.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am sorry, but as a newbie to this, I dont know what you mean.  How do I initialize the integers in the main class so that I can reference them in child classes.  That is what I was attempting to do.  I am not sure how to do this?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with main versus child class. This is about completely different objects. "mort1", "m", "t", and "i" are different objects. "mort1.setData(loan, interest, years)" invokes a function that initializes mort1's class members. It does nothing to initialize the other objects. It's just like if you have "int a,b;", and then later "a=5", this does absolutely nothing to affect b's value. It is true that "m", "t", and "i" have a "MortgageCalc" superclass. But just because you initialized "MortgatgeCalc mort1", doesn't mean that you've initialized m's, t's, or i's MortgageCalc.